# Very Low Speaker sound in Ubuntu 17.04.

Tags: 17.04

The sound is very less from speakers(built-in).
the sound is ok with the Headphones.
Any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to **Sound Settings** from the volume icon in the panel, you can click "Allow louder than 100%" - this might improve your volume.

If it's something hardware-related, maybe some others would be able to help

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem

please solve this one too
https://askubuntu.com/questions/942708/unable-to-access-internet-via-lan-cable-in-ubuntu-17-04